# How to Mock a Func<T> Parameter for Constructor Injection C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, mocking

I am writing TestCases and have need to Mock Items for my Dependency Injection enabled Constructor:

```
public MainViewModel(
     INetworkConnectivity networkConnectivity,
     IMenuConfiguration configuration,
     IDialogService dialogService,
     IAppMgr appManager,
     IAutoJobSync autoJobSync,
     IAutoJobSyncResults autoJobSyncResults,
     ITaskDetailsDataLayer taskDetailsDataLayer,
     AmeMenuPresenter ameMenuPresenter,
     IDispatcherContext dispatcherContext,
     IMessenger messenger,
     Func<IUserTasksDataLayer> userTasksDataLayerFactory,
     INonResidentJobUtilities nonResidentJobUtilities)
```

The Interfaced Items are simple enough....eg, `var mockNetworkConnectivity = new Mock<INetworkConnectivity>()`

**I am really lost as how to Mock** `Func<IUserTasksDataLayer> userTasksDataLayerFactory`

I am not permitted to change the Constructor I must test the Constructor as given to me.

here is definition of IUserTaskDataLayer:

```
public interface IUserTasksDataLayer
   {
      void Initialize(IDialogService dialogService, INonResidentJobUtilities nonResidentJobUtilities);
      
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to mock that. Since a delegate is a *callback*, you can already put whatever you want in there. Just provide a lambda:

```cs
var mv = new MainViewModel(mockNetworkConnectivity.Object, mockMenuConfiguration.Object, ..., () => Mock.Of<IUserTasksDataLayer>(), ...);
```

This returns a new mock when the delegate is invoked by the constructor. Alternatively, of course you can also just return a constant, such as `null`.

Comment: Thanks... Got to Compile Step. I will mark as answered fairly soon after I get a few things tested